# How to save a jpg image to android phone with as3

Tags: android, image, actionscript-3, save, jpeg

I'm trying to save an image to my android phone is a specific directory.
Somehow I spent hours but couldn't get it to work. I hope someone can help me understand why my code isn't working or if there is another way to do it.

```
public function SaveTheImage(me:MouseEvent):void
{       
    ImageSaverBMD.draw(ImageHolder);

    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var jpgBytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(ImageSaverBMD);

    var myFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("/sdcard / DCIM / Camera/testingimage.jpg");
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fs.open(myFile, FileMode.WRITE);
    fs.writeBytes(jpgBytes, 0, jpgBytes.length);
    fs.close();  
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise ! have you declared permissions on your Manifest ? has your app crashed on launch ? what is your logcat showing ? what ...

Answer (score 0):

There are many steps in your algorithm that could cause the bug, with the code you provided I could make a few guesses, but there is a better way.

First of all try this code:

```
var s:Shape = new Shape();
s.graphics.beginFill(0);
s.graphics.drawCircle( 20, 20, 20);
s.graphics.endFill();

var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(40, 40, false);
bd.draw(s);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var bytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bd);

var f:File = File.applicationDirectory;
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(bytes);
fs.close();
```

This should save a 80x80 pixels black circle in your provided directory. See if it works. If not: check permissions to have external storage.

If it works, start removing the code block-by-block from top to bottom:

- Remove the top two blocks and put your `ImageSaverBMD.draw(ImageHolder)` line. Maybe the problem is with that class? It could be that the bitmap data size was wrong or the matrix for drawing had incorrect translation.
- The JPGEncoder is probably OK, it's a common used framework, but sometimes when I copy it into my source files I need to change the package in the .as file. Is your package correct?
- Your URL in the File object has spaces, could that be your problem, try using a simple URL first and see if that works. It could be the problem that you try to navigate to an absolute URL with a relative URL pattern (I could be wrong on this, usually I have different approach of navigating to a folder).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much,
I will try your code i want thepicture will be added to the cameraroll images how do i get to that directory? From your code i understand that the file will be saved to the app directory, would i be able to see it in the camera roll i use air for android.
Again thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Ok, found the problem the only problem was the resolvepath probably the wrong path except this everything works great. Now the next problem is with the refresh gallery i need to to turn off the device in order to see the pictures in the camera roll so i need to use the extension refreshgallery but there is no xample of how to use it... ( why everything has to have a problem...  )

Comment: If your current question about saving a file is answered, I'd say accept this answer and make a question about your extension, it's more chance you'll have an answer as answering in the comment about a different thing would be off-topic.

Comment: thank you for all your help i succeeded to save image to a file but i ma facing another problem, the image saved is laying on the side is there a way to save the file that will stand correctly?

Comment: rotate the object, then make a BitmapData object out of it and save it.

Comment: Thankx i tried that but didnt worked but maybe i didnt do it correctly, can you make a simple code for me to try? Thnx

Answer (score -1):

```
private function export():void
{

        var today_date:Date = new Date();
        var thismonth:uint = today_date.getMonth();
        var today_time;
        var currentTime:Date = new Date();
        var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
        var hours = currentTime.getHours() * 30 + currentTime.getMinutes() / 2;

        var mnth:Array = new Array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
        var fileName:String = (today_date.getDate()+mnth[thismonth]+today_date.getFullYear()+"_"+currentTime.hours + currentTime.minutes + currentTime.seconds+".png");
        //trace(fileName);// displays current date in United States date format
        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(board.width, board.height);//(600, 290);

        bmd.draw(board);

        var ba:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);
       // var file:File = File.applicationDirectory;
        //var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
        var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
        var targetFile : File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
        //var targetFile : File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fileName);
        fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(ba);
        fs.close();

        //file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveSuccessful);
        saveDialog = new SaveDialog();

        addChild(saveDialog);
        test = setInterval(showMessage,2000);
        //var test = setInterval(showMessage,3000);
        saveDialog.closeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, closeSaveDialog);
        //file.save(ba, fileName);
    }
```